# /proc/net/dev alternative on Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, networking

I have a program in C that reads /proc/net/dev and parses the number of bytes downloaded and uploaded. I use it to show notifications when I'm about to cross certain threshold and to keep statistics of download/upload.

My question is, how do I make this work on Windows as well? Is there any file with the same function as /proc/net/dev on Unix systems?

Or how do I get number of bytes transferred since boot on Windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C program you could do something such as `system('netstat -e')` and parse the results. Other netstat options may help for this type of thing as well.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't expect it to be that easy :).

Comment: Be warned that this may not be forwards compatible.  There's no guarantee that the format of the output won't change.

Answer (score 1):

With Powershell you can run `Get-NetAdapterStatistics` to see sent and received bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The [GetPerTcpConnectionEStats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485738(v=vs.85).aspx) function appears to provide the information you're looking for.  You'll need to call [GetTcpTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366026(v=vs.85).aspx) first to enumerate the connections.